# ERROR 'dependencies.dependency.version' for stax:stax-api:jar is missing

Tags: maven

When I run clean install on my java project, I get the error msg mentioned in the title. My pom looks like this:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I know that this error messages comes up because the tag version is missing but I am wondering why is this issue if clean install was working before I have reseted my windows. Beside that the my other colleagues can build the project without any problem